# Mac file type incorrectly identified in finder

Tags: mac

I use an OS X Yosemite Mac, mainly to program an embroidery machine. Most of the design files are `*.jef` files.
They correctly open in Embrilliance Aus, but their type is listed incorrectly in Finder. They should be identified as a Janome file, but are identified as Viking.

How do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

That association was most likely made by the installing app and is non-trivial to change. Modifying it would require modifying the Launch Services Database and there are no end-user provided tools to do so.

According the authors of [Embrilliance](https://embrilliance.com/about), their first development was a "shareware product for embroiderers to view and convert HUS files for their Husqvarna Viking machines," which might be where the "Viking" descriptor comes from.

If it bothers you enough, I recommend contacting the authors of the software.